# Is it possible to have editable menu item?

Tags: extjs6.5

I am using Extjs 6.5.3. I want to have a menu which will have editable menu items. Is it possible to have editor in menu item and on click of menu item it should start editing? Please help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you want to edit, exactly?

Comment: Menu item. Suppose I have menu as                                                                                    Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        items: [{
        text: 'plain item 1'
    },{
        text: 'plain item 2'
    }
});                                                                                                                           I wnat to edit 'plain item 2' and 'plain text 1'. On click of this I want to have number field as editor.

Comment: I think you will need to create custom menu having editable component as menu item. But this needs to be checked.